# Net Core 3.1 IHttpClientFactory/HttpClient Slow on First Request

Tags: c#, performance, asp.net-core, httpclient

I have a .Net Core 3.1 app. In the app, I use the IHttpClientFactory to create an HttpClient. When I make a call using SendAsync, the first request takes over 2 seconds whereas subsequent requests take less than 100 ms. This is not acceptable performance for a production application.

I have also noticed that it happens if I don't make any requests for a while. I came across the PooledConnectionIdleTimeout property, which defaults to 2 minutes, and I can extend that time, but that would only work for pooled connections that already exist, not when needing to create a new one.
I configure the HttpClient in my Startup.cs as such:

```
 services.AddHttpClient("HttpClient",
            h =>
            {
                h.BaseAddress = new Uri(Configuration["PythonUrl"]);
            });
```

Use the HttpClient like this:

```
 var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("HttpClient");
 var res = await client.GetAsync(nameof(Accounts).ToLower() + "/" + id.ToString() + "/");
```

when the "Configuration["PythonUrl"]" contains PC name,like this :

```
{
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "PythonUrl": "http://PC202003261059:8000/",
  "url": "http://*:5000"
}
```

The HttpClient's first request becomes very slow. Can anything be done to avoid this?

Comment: This is seemingly little to do with HttpClient or ClientFactory, and more likely the webserver spinning up or dns resolution or some other issue, in short there is no switch in HttpClient to say, GoFasterOnFirstLoad = true

Comment: @TheGeneral I don't think so, I think it may be due to the DNS parsing of httpclient

Comment: HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 var res = await client.GetAsync("http://PC202003261059:8000/accounts/2/");
    like this, it also will be slow

Comment: It's not uncommon for first requests to be slow due to lazy initialization. You can always perform a dummy request at startup to warm up your service before taking on real traffic.

Comment: @ https://stackoverflow.com/users/6765564/kelvin  Thanks first, After my test,I found that it may be cause by DNS, but I don't know why the httpclient becomes very slow with DNS.

Comment: @Cony are you hosting your app in IIS?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found a solution that works well for me.
Note that this solution will only work for IIS hosted WebApps.

When hosting an application in IIS, the AppPool is responsible for actually running it. However, it only starts the application when it receives the first request. This is fine in most situations and is therefore the default setting, but this leads to a slow first request.

1. In IIS manager, right click on the Application Pool that runs your
   app and select '**Advanced Settings**'.  Set '**Start Mode**' to '**Always
   Running**'.
2. Rick-Click your Site and under '**Manage Website**' select '**Advanced
   Settings**'. Set '**Preload Enabled**' to '**true**'.

This should make the first request faster and won't put your AppPool to sleep after some time. It should also be noted that this *may* impact the performance of other apps hosted on the same server.

This [article](https://taithienbo.medium.com/how-to-auto-start-and-keep-an-asp-net-core-web-application-running-on-iis-9acc0fb6784b) helped me with this.

**Disclaimer:** the first request might still be slower due to several reason (some of which may be client-side like DNS requests, or network-related lost packets, poor internet connection etc...).